# How to add raw input values in Python?

Tags: python, input, addition

I'm trying to get 2 raw input values added together. Here's the code:

```
def number_of_limbs(legs, arms, limbs):
    print "You have %s legs O.o" % legs
    print "You also have %s arms o.O" % arms
    print "You have %r limbs!! O.O" % limbs

legs = int(raw_input("How many legs do you have? "))
arms = int(raw_input("And how many arms do you have? ")
limbs = legs + arms

number_of_limbs(legs, arms, limbs)
```

It's supposed to ask how many legs, how many arms, and then add them together. Then tell how
many limbs in total. I'm in lesson 19 of learn python the hard way so that's why i'm doing the "def" thing at the top. I realize there's easier ways to do the exact same thing but i'm trying to grasp the concept of this particular thing.

When I run it, it says I have 2 arms, 2 legs, and 22 limbs. How do I get it to add legs and arms and not just push the two numbers next to each other?

Now it's just saying

```
 File "ex1.py", line 8
    limb = legs + arms
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: That's correct. "2" + "2" = "22". :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to cast them as ints:

```
legs = int(raw_input("How many legs do you have? "))
arms = int(raw_input("And how many arms do you have? "))
```

#### Example

```
>>> number_of_limbs(legs, arms, limbs)
You have 2 legs O.o
You also have 2 arms o.O
You have 4 limbs!! O.O
```

This is because you are adding `strings` and when you do `string+string` it simply concatenates the two strings together. This is because the default type of `raw_input` is `str`

```
>>> '2'+'2'
'22'
>>> int('2')+int('2')
4
```

Comment: I changed them to ints but now it's saying:SyntaxError: invalid syntax with a little arrow pointing to the "s" after "limbs" on line 8. Getting rid of the "s" just makes it point to the "b".

Comment: @user3529201, Can you update your question with changed code?

Comment: Sorry, about that! Just did Ohh I get what you mean now! One sec

Comment: @user3529201, Your second raw_input. You forgot the second closing `)`

Comment: Thanks you so much! It works now :) Sorry for asking the obvious lol I really don't understand programming, which is why I'm learning! Yes, I'll accept it!

Comment: @sshashank124 Ask to accept, don't pester them to accept twice.

Answer (score 4):

Convert them to integers:

```
legs = int(raw_input("How many legs do you have? "))
arms = int(raw_input("And how many arms do you have? "))
```

---

At the moment they are strings, this is the default datatype from `raw_input.`

```
>>> example = raw_input()
2
>>> type(example)
<class 'str'>
```

When you add two strings together (right there you have `'2'` and `'2'`), Python just concatenates them into one single string. (So in that case it will result in `'22'`)

```
>>> '2' + '2'
'22'
```

---

It should now give the correct result.

A minimal example of what the fixed version does:

```
>>> legs = int(raw_input())
2
>>> arms = int(raw_input())
2
>>> limbs = legs + arms
>>> limbs
4
```

You can now pass that to the function without trouble.